# Initializing PriorityQueue with Comparator

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

The following code is complained by compiler (Java 8) that there is no suitable constructor:

```
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue((ListNode n1, ListNode n2) -> n1.val - n2.val)
```

However, creating the Comparator upfront and then pass it to the PriorityQueue works,

```
Comparator<ListNode> c = (ListNode n1, ListNode n2) -> n1.val - n2.val;
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue(c);
```

I wonder why the first approach fails? Is it because the compiler cannot infer the Comparator type from the lambda expression?

Comment: You're using a raw type. What if you use `new PriorityQueue<>(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using this `PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)` constructor. And you did not provide any type for `E`, where E should be `ListNode`. To fix your code just write it like this

```java
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>((ListNode n1, ListNode n2) -> n1.val - n2.val);
// or
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((ListNode n1, ListNode n2) -> n1.val - n2.val);
```

Comment: As this is Java 7+ one can use the [diamond operator](https://howtodoinjava.com/java7/improved-type-inference-in-java-7/) (i.e. `<>`).

Comment: @Slaw, yes, this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: When the target type is known, the lambda expression doesn’t need explicit types anymore, so `PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<>((n1, n2) -> n1.val - n2.val);` would do, but the standard disclaimer applies: *this only works when the distance between two values is guaranteed to be within the signed `int` range*. Which doesn’t hold for arbitrary `int` values, hence, it should rather be `PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap=new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(n->n.val));`